# Coherence cache not returning data for passed Filter

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

Below query is not returning data.
Data is present. Checked with EQUALS operator.

```
AndFilter(EqualsFilter(KeyExtractor(extractor=.getSubscriberCode()), JACK), ContainsAnyFilter(KeyExtractor(extractor=.getNumber()), [43]))
```

Below is the CoHQL transformation of above filter.

```
select * from MyCache where key().subscriberCode="JACK" and key().number contains any ("43");
```

What is wrong in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `ContainsAnyFilter` javadoc:

> Filter which tests a Collection or Object array value returned from a method invocation for containment of any value in a Set

A guess your `key.getNumber()` returns single value, not a collection. And since `ContainsAnyFilter` operates on collections and arrays, it simply filter out all cache enties.

You should probably try `InFilter` instead of `ContainsAnyFilter`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even We were thinking about the same.

I would like to point one thing here which is the same contains any filter works in one Environment A and does not work in Environment B. The interesting part is, it works in Environment B for some time and then stops returning data.

Comment: In that case I have to admit that I can't even guess, why it is working and then stops.